# Magento Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Themeframework_Helper_Theme' not found in

Tags: magento, fatal-error

Here is my code.

```
public static function helper($name) {
   $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name; 
   if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
      $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name); 
      self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass); 
   }
   return self::registry($registryKey); 
 }
```

It is getting this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Themeframework_Helper_Theme' not found in
>   /var/www/clients/client66/web83/web/app/Mage.php on line 546

Please help my figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Show the code from the Mage.php. Lines 540 - 550 where the error is coming from..

Comment: */
    public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should check your module **config.xml** file if you have defined the path for the Helpers:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <themeframework>
            <class>Packagename_Themeframework_Helper</class>
        </themeframework>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Make sure the class file: **app/code/local/Packagename/Themeframework/Helper/Theme.php** (or if it is defined in the community folder: **app/code/community/Packagename/Themeframework/Helper/Theme.php**) exists.

Replace the **Packagename** with the name of your package.